# SQL dynamic query in ADF

Tags: sql, azure, ssms, azure-data-factory, pipeline

I have SQL dynamic query with a "?" that needs to be replaced with pipeline parameters. The fetched query has a question mark "?" how to replace that?

I tried passing the parameters but ADF doesn't recognize the ? symbol and the correct parameters are not passed

Comment: SSMS is just an IDE-like application that is used with several products such as (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure Synapse. SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question here. What product are you actually using for your data engine?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the issue that you are facing ?

Comment: the query is `declare @SourceID int, @datafileid int set @SourceID=?  set @datafileid=? update ....` how to supply values for these "?" in ADF pipeline dynamically
@saideep

Comment: Do you have the values for these stored in parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can either use `concat` function to concatenate the query with your dynamic content i.e., your parameters or you can use string interpolation (`@{...}`).
- Either way, you can build a dynamic query where you will be using parameters (with values as you wish).
- Consider, you want to build a query as specified in the comment, and have 2 parameters as shown in the below image:

[image]

- You can use the following dynamic content to build the query. Enclose the parameter within `@{...}` (string interpolation) wherever required:

```
Declare @SourceID int, @datafileid int;
Set @SourceID=@{pipeline().parameters.source_id};
Set @datafileid=@{pipeline().parameters.datafield}
```

- The above would generate the query as shown in the below image:

[image]

- You can either directly use similar dynamic content wherever you are using the query or store the value in a `set variable` activity and use that variable in place of query.